# Sharing dynamic client and server-side content between JSP's

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I've done quite a lot of searching about capabilities of JSPs and have been unable to find a concise answer to my issue.

I am currently writing a web application which uses a single jsp (with an imported CSS) to build a site with multiple functionalities. Specifically, the application has the ability to read and write data from/to an external server, as well as update user content and info.

For the sake of aesthetics and clarity, it makes the most sense to designate different areas of the site to each of these tasks, one at a time. Rather than attempt to use page divisions and conditional statements to control their visibility and execution, I want to essentially "cut up" the logic behind this dynamic content and spread it across multiple JSPs to allow for more organized editing, testing, and modification of the code by both a web developer and programmer, without either necessarily having to collaborate.

Assuming that all of the JSPs involved have the appropriate imports, are there any essential measures I need to take to allow seamless sharing of content between these JSPs? For example, if a user writes to the server and stores their data as some entity, (from a page with tools from one jsp) will the functions used to query the database work if I simply copy that code into another jsp and have the user navigate to that page in order to access that persisted data?

Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Learn the design pattern [Model–view–controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). It'll great to help you solve many of your project problems. And your architecture will more maintainable and scalable. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/3542297#3542297) and [here](http://engineerbabu.in/2012/07/03/jsps-and-servlets-tutorial-15-understanding-the-mvc-pattern/) for more information about the implementation of this pattern with JSP.

Comment: Thank you! I've come across MVC several times and didn't give it much thought, but that's probably the way to go. I appreciate the advice!